# Rails Routing: One controller. One model with type. Multiple routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have one model named Factors, which has two types: `['personal', 'advisor']`

I want to have one controller `FactorsController` that has all the same actions for both types of `Factors`, but only ever uses one type. The type that it uses is based on the route used to get there. For example,

`/personal` would route to `factors#index` and populate `@factors` with `Factor.personal`
`/advisors` would route to `factors#index` and populate `@factors` with `Factor.advisors`

How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to the routes

```
type_regexp = Regexp.new([:personal, :advisor].join("|"))
resources :factors, path: ':type', constraints: { type: type_regexp }
```

and you will be able to user `params[:type]` in the controllers, that gives you flexibility in case you wanna changes the routes in the future.

This also gives you the ability to use `factors_path(type: :personal)` in the views.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your routes:

```
resources :factors, :path => :personal
resources :factors, :path => :advisor
```

This will then have both /personal and /advisor. You'll then want to have factors#index determine which path was used (you could use `request.url`) and populate `@factors` accordingly.

Comment: I have an issue that I am running into that I wonder if you could shed some light on:

In the views I want to be able to use all the same views since everything is the same in all of them, just with the different data. The problem is that there is one thing that changes in the views: the paths. What would be the best way to organize injecting different paths into the views? 

One thing I thought of doing was something like `eval("edit_#{@factor_type}_path(@factor)` where `@factor_type` is either `personal` or `advisor`

Comment: However, I'm not that interested in using eval

Comment: The best way to address this is to use a helper. Add `def edit_factor_path(factor)` to `app/heplers/application_helper.rb`

Comment: This answer is a bad practice, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would create three controllers:

```
class PersonalController < FactorController
  def factor
    Factor.personal
  end
end

class AdvisorController < FactorController
  def factor
    Factor.advisors
  end
end

class FactorController < ApplicationController
  #all the shared stuff here, using the factor method from each in your methods
end
```

and then the routes would be:

```
route '/personal' => PersonalController#index
route '/advisors' => AdvisorController#index
```